# Refresh repository after run stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following action in my WebAPI project that runs stored procedure to update (and some others operations) `People` table:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SetAsMain(int id)
{
    People people = repository.GetById(id);

    if (people == null)
    {
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("No people with ID = {1}", id));
    }

    if (people.IsMain)
    {
        return ReturnMsg(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("{0} is already set as main", people.FullName)); 
    }

    try
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("PeopleID", id.ToString());                

        repository.ExecProcedure("usp_PeopleSetMain", parameters);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, repository.GetById(id)); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have a problem with retrieve data after update by stored proc. In this place:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, repository.GetById(id));
```

I get the same data as it was before the update. But when I call this method again then there will be an actual data.

How can I refresh data in my repository?

Could you tell me why `repository.GetById(id)` never fetches a new data after `ExecProcedure`. 
Let me know if I have to add more information

**UPDATE** 
Method GetById in my repository:

```
public T GetById(object id)
{
   return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

Comment: `Find` returns the entity immediately without going to the data store if it already exists in the context. You can reset the context or detach the entity then do `Find` again, hard to say what is best without knowing how your respository works.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder. I didn't know it about `Find`. How can I detach the entity?

Comment: you can replace Find by FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault which will excecute SQL

Comment: @MegaTron ObjectContext has a Detach method but its probably better to go with ieaglle's suggestion.

Comment: There's also [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) method which can be useful.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try it and write result here. Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because Entity Framework context already contains your object. Method `Find(id)` always checks if object exists in the context and if it is there, Entity Framework will not query the database. Stored procedures do not change context objects because they are executed directly against the database, that's why you don't see an updated values in your entity.

You can workaround this with 1 of the following things:

1. Stop entity tracking in the context
2. Use `AsNoTracking()` to query entity without following tracking.
3. Query object using `First(...)`, `FirstOrDefault(...)`, `Single(...)` etc. after executing stored procedure.

I would recommend you to go with option 1 or 2. Option 1:

```
context.Entry(people).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

If you run earlier version of Entity Framework, you should detach object:

```
context.People.Detach(people);
```

---

(Thanks ieaglle) You could also query your entities turning off tracking right away (Option 2):

```
context.People.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: `AsNoTracking` IMO is better because it does not attach entity to context in the first place. In your example `yourEntity` will be attached before your line.

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

[DbSet.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) behaves the next way:

> If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned.

So `Find` won't query DB for your new updated entity it will just take cached old one.

To workaround this feature you have couple of options:

- Explicitly force EF to query DB for new entity by using `.FirstOrDefault`, `.SingleOrDefault` or any other method that triggers query execution;
- Do not attach entities to the context in the first place by using [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx).